# Django: control time of TemporaryUploadedFile life

Tags: django, file-upload

I have form in my django app. User can do prior upload of files before submitting the form. In handler for uploaded files I use TemporaryUploadedFile. So - files are stored in /tmp directory. This handler send the response to the form - JSON object, which contains file path and file extension. This information collects in array.

After submitting the form this array is serialized. And here is the problem - when the form handler receive form data and array of file names and try to access this files - here is the error "no such file".

So, my question is - how I can solve this problem? Maybe I can set the life time of this files for a bigger time? Or maybe I should use UploadedFile instead of TemporaryUploadedFile.

TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TemporaryUploadedFile` uses `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`. The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile) have this to say:

> ```
> tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile([mode='w+b'[, bufsize=-1[, suffix=''[, prefix='tmp'[, dir=None[, delete=True]]]]]])
> ```
>
> This function operates
>   exactly as TemporaryFile() does, except that the file is guaranteed to
>   have a visible name in the file system (on Unix, the directory entry
>   is not unlinked). That name can be retrieved from the name attribute
>   of the file object. Whether the name can be used to open the file a
>   second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies
>   across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT
>   or later). *If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as
>   soon as it is closed* (emphasis mine).
>
> The returned object is always a file-like object whose file attribute
>   is the underlying true file object. This file-like object can be used
>   in a with statement, just like a normal file.

So, the default behavior here is to delete the file as soon as it's closed, which it will be, automatically after the initial processing. So you have two choices. You can either subclass [`TemporaryUploadedFile`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py) and override the `__init__` method so that you can pass `delete=False` to `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` (but then you need to remember to manually delete the file when you're done to avoid build-up of old temporary files), or you can make sure to move your `TemporaryUploadedFile` somewhere else before returning from processing the upload, and send the new location back instead.

It would not be appropriate to use `UploadedFile` because it's a base class and not intended to be instantiated, itself.

Comment: Thx! But I face some troubles when tried to implement this. When I process request.FILES data in upload handler - request.FILES contains TemporaryUploadedFile objects (native class, not another implemented by me). So, files will be deleted anyway.

Comment: Then, you will need to manually save the files to a new location.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris Pratt pointed above, you can subclass not TemporaryUploadedFile but TemporaryFileUploadHandler, and then create your own `CustomTemporaryUploadedFile` which will also use NamedTemporaryFile but with `delete = False`. I used it already in production environment and it's 100% guaranteed xD

```
## Custom Temporary file Upload Handlet to use if django settings
class CustomTemporaryFileUploadHandler(TemporaryFileUploadHandler):

    def new_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
       """
       Create the file object to append to as data is coming in.
       """
       super().new_file(*args, **kwargs)
       self.file = CustomTemporaryUploadedFile(
            self.file_name, self.content_type, 0, self.charset, self.content_type_extra
       )



class CustomTemporaryUploadedFile(UploadedFile):
"""
A file uploaded to a temporary location (i.e. stream-to-disk).
"""

    def __init__(self, name, content_type, size, charset, content_type_extra=None):
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
        file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
            suffix=".upload" + ext, dir=settings.FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR, delete=False
        )
        super().__init__(file, name, content_type, size, charset, content_type_extra)

    def temporary_file_path(self):
        """Return the full path of this file."""
        return self.file.name

    def close(self):
        try:
            return self.file.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # The file was moved or deleted before the tempfile could unlink
            # it. Still sets self.file.close_called and calls
            # self.file.file.close() before the exception.
            pass
```

Finaly, in your settings_common.py, and this:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
   'path.to.your.CustomTemporaryFileUploadHandler'
]
```